# Save chart object from performanceanalytics package

Tags: r, ggplot2, performanceanalytics

Is it possible to save the chart object from the `performanceanalytics` package into an object like one can do with the `ggplot2` or `lattice` chart?

For example [this snail trail chart](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/PerformanceAnalytics/docs/chart.SnailTrail).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

If you look at the source code of `chart.SnailTrail`, you can see that it uses basic plotting functionality (e.g. `plot.new()`, `points()`, `segments()`, `text()`, `axis()`, `title()`, `legend()`).

Of course you could rewrite the function with `ggplot2` functions instead. If you do so, I suggest making the new function available as an answer to your question, in your own package or in the `PerformanceAnalytics` package.